# Rxjs use subject with refCount

Tags: javascript, rxjs

When you need to share the observable execution you can use the share operator which performs the `publish()` and `refCount()` methods, but when working with `Subjects` how can I use `refCount()`?

```
new Subject().refCount()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `refCount()` isn't like the other operators.

When you use `publish()` operator it returns an instance of [`ConnectableObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts). [`refCount()` is an operator specific only to `ConnectableObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L49) and you won't find it in any other Observable.

A good question is what you want to achieve with `refCount()` and `Subject` because `refCount()` really makes sense only where you want to subscribe/unsubscribe from a source Observable (I don't know what your particular use-case is).

Anyway, you can always use `(new Subject()).publish().refCount()` if it makes sense.

Comment: I have multiple observers that need to share the same execution, and I want to use refCount for automatically unsubscribe from the subject when the number of observers is 0.

Comment: And I need to use Subject because I want to call next() manually

Comment: @undefined Then use the Subject if you need it. Eg: `let source = new Subject(); let obs = source.publish().refCount(); obs.subscribe(....)`

Comment: But the publish() is an alias for multicast with subject, that's weird.

Comment: @undefined Well, if you need to use a `Subject` and need to use `refCount()` than there's probably no other choice. However, I'd recommend to rethink whether you really need to automatically unsubscribe from the `Subject` because I think this shouldn't be necessary (although I don't know you exact usecase)

Answer (score 1):

A `Subject` is already *hot*, meaning that there is no need for an additional use of `refCount` or `publish` or the like.

This is an excerpt from the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md):

> In this way, the subject can act as a **proxy for a group of subscribers** and a source. [...] In addition, you can use subjects to **broadcast data to multiple subscribers**.

Comment: So you are saying the Subject is automatically unsubscribe when he doesn't have any observers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - in the code you provided there is no source your `Subject` subscribes to - so it cannot unsubscribe from anything.

Comment: Yes, this is only a peace, I have multiple observers.

Comment: Maybe you should post more code then with an actual use-case, combining multiple observable sounds to me more like a case of `zip`, `combineLatest`, `merge` or some other combination-operator